# How to import custom exported js functions in background.js on electron vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, electron-builder

I'm developing a desktop application using Electron and Vue. I'm trying to use a custom exported function inside my `background.js` file but I'm getting the following error:

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| export class CustomPojo {
>   customVariable;
| 
|   constructor(variable) {

 @ ./src/test/index.js 2:0-49 5:17-21
 @ ./src/background.js
 @ multi ./src/background.js
```

I have the following folder structure:

```
- src
-- test.js
- utils
-- customPojo.js
- background.js
```

The `test.js` has a simple export function that just does a console log to debug the application:

```
import { c } from "@/utils/customPojo";

export function test() {
    c.whatever();
    console.log("testing);
}
```

The `customPojo.js` has the following content:

```
export class CustomPojo {
    customVariable;

    constructor(variable) {
        this.customVariable = variable;
    }

    async whatever(){}
}
```

I'm importing the `test` function in my `background.js` like that:

```
import { test } from './test';
```

Anyone has a clue about what's happening? I've googled about the error, but I'm unable to make this work.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to import a custom function in my `background.js` to reuse it.

Comment: But why are you importing it in `background.js` if you want to use it within your Vue application? You should be importing it inside of `main.js`.

Comment: @recoilnetworks Because I wanted that when my application starts `(app.on("ready"))`,  it calls the `test` function

Comment: So just call it from "router.isReady().then()" in the "main.js" file.